# undefined / null get accepted as value for conditional type even if it shouldn't

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Should't this throw a compiler error?

```
type Test<T extends number | string> = { v: T extends number ? true : false }
const test: Test<1> = { v: undefined }
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does if you have the `strictNullChecks` flag enabled in your `tsconfig.json`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8MoQB7AgOwCbymwFcBbAIwgCcoAfKRSgS2wHMA+KAXigG8oA3AFyw0mHPkKkK1APxRglItGEAzAIYAbeNAC+AKD0BjAPbZE8hMGFxESAIwdufIVCJ4IK5hFxQdQA)